# Where to start from and how to proceed for finding the resistance here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Can anyone kindly help me in finding the effective resistance between A and B in the below goven case ? Each resistor is of 16 ohm ..
[image]

Thank you .

Comment: These have become more of a solve the puzzle problem, and less like a physics problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each resistor is 16 ohms then you can reduce the 4 parallel resistors on each side to one 4-ohm resistor.

This leaves you with one 4-ohm resistor between A and B, in parallel with 3 4-ohm resistors in series going B-C-D-A.  So, 4 ohms in parallel with 12 ohms.

The formula for parallel resistors is

- (R1 * R2) / (R1 + R2)
- (4 * 12) / (4 + 12)
- 48 / 16
- 3

Answer (score 3):

First off, reduce those 4 resistors in each side to just one resistor - they are actually 4 in parallel. It then becomes simple.

Comment: So , each square is of 4 ohm resistance and all the four 4 ohm resistances are in parallel again to get and effective resistance of 1 ohm . Am I right sir ?

Comment: @SaravananRamesh - Not quite.  Think about it some more.

Answer (score 1):

Could you solve it if the diagram looked like this?

```
           4         4         4
      |---/\/\/\----/\/\/\----/\/\/\----|
A ----|                4                |---- B
      |-------------/\/\/\--------------|
```

If so, then you just need to figure out why this is the same circuit as you have above (Dirk Bruere's answer should help a lot).